# What is the use of dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier?

Tags: mapkit

I have seen in many mapkit examples that we can dequeue a reusable annotation view with the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` of the map view, but where would this annotation view come from ? Is it created programmatically before ? What is the point of it compared to creating it each time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier is not creating new AnnotationViews.
It is reCycling. Very much like UITableViewCell deQueue.

For ram saving purposes, annotationViews for annotations which get out of visible border of map are reUsed for visible annotations.

dequeue looks for an annotation view which is out of visible area.
If it finds it, it salvages it and use it. You have to reFurnish the recycled view.

If it can not salvage an old view, it creates a new one and registers it for reCycling with deQueue.

Say u have 20 annotations attached to mapview.
5 is on screen , 15 is out of sight.
There are not 20 annotationviews for 20 annotations if not necessary.
Max 7-8 annotationViews for whole 20 annotations.

Say programatically you created a 21st annotation and it is in sight.
One view out of 8 stolen now. 1 left for backup.

Say u cretaed another 2 which are visible, i view gotten from backup, and 1 view created now.

It is for optimal resource usage.

Comment: Oh ok, so it's basically like in table views ? Thank you !

Comment: When you say refurnish, at which point ? If I had set some custom properties of my view, must I set them again ? Or only the content such as titles ?

Comment: When mapView:viewForAnnotation: called, you have to renew everything which are custom. It will be called once when creation or recyling occurs for an annotation. When an annotion lose its view ( get outta sight ) and reEnters sight, it will be called again. Please vote up, if you like it.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant ! Thank you.